# jQuery $.inArray always returns -1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

I am try to match the keyword "BN to" but it appears that this is not working out for me, the result is always "-1". What am I doing wrong?

```
var yourArray = ["BNI to ALPHA", "BNI to BRAVO", "BNI to CHARLIE"]

var found = $.inArray('BNI to', yourArray)

alert(found)

}
```

Comment: You are searching for a member inside the array with a string like this "Bni to" and theres no member with that specific string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.inArray()` function tells you where a given value can be found the array. Your string is not equal to any member of the array, so the return value is `-1`.

I think what you're looking for could be `Array.prototype.findIndex`:

```
var found = yourArray.findIndex(function(s) {
  return s.startsWith("BNI to");
});
```

The `.findIndex()` function is an ES2015 thing, and not supported by Internet Explorer yet (according to MDN). [There's a Polyfill to use however.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)